# Bootstrap collapse works to hide, but not to show

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, absolute

In short, this is happening: https://jsfiddle.net/exr4hv8z/2/ (try mousing over the buttons and then mousing out a few times)

For whatever reason, elements collapse away to hide just fine, but the other element that is supposed to collapse in to view wont animate and simply pops in once the other element is done.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_bar">

<a href="index.php">
    <div class="navbutton_background background_normal collapse in"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_hover collapse" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_click collapse" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <button class="navbutton rightborder">Home</button>
</a>

<a href="forum.php">
    <div class="navbutton_background background_normal collapse in left_1"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_hover collapse left_1" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_click collapse left_1" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <button class="navbutton leftborder rightborder left_1">Forums</button>
</a>

<a href="servers.php">
    <div class="navbutton_background background_normal collapse in left_2"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_hover collapse left_2" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_click collapse left_2" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <button class="navbutton leftborder rightborder left_2">Servers</button>
</a>

<a href="contact.php">
    <div class="navbutton_background background_normal collapse in left_3"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_hover collapse left_3" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_click collapse left_3" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <button class="navbutton leftborder rightborder left_3">Contact</button>
</a>

<a href="about.php">
    <div class="navbutton_background background_normal collapse in left_4"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_hover collapse left_4" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <div class="navbutton_background background_click collapse left_4" style="height: 0;"></div>
    <button class="navbutton leftborder left_4">About</button>
</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_bar
{
background-color: rgba(27, 27, 27, 1);

width: 100%;
height: 5rem;

border-width: 10%;

margin-top: 2rem;

position: relative;
}

.navbutton
{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 1);

font-weight: bold;

width: 20%;
height: 100%;

position: absolute;

z-index: 1;

border: 0;
border-bottom: 0.5rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navbutton_background
{
width: 20%;
height: 100%;

position: absolute;
}

/* Colors for button states */
.background_normal { background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1); }
.background_hover { background-color: rgba(0, 190, 220, 1); }
.background_click { background-color: rgba(0, 210, 240, 1); }

/* Left_# are for positioning each individual button 20*#% away from the left side */
.left_1 { left: 20%; }
.left_2 { left: 40%; }
.left_3 { left: 60%; }
.left_4 { left: 80%; }

.leftborder { border-left: 0.3rem dashed rgba(27, 27, 27, 1); }
.rightborder { border-right: 0.3rem dashed rgba(27, 27, 27, 1); }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#nav_bar a").mouseover (function () {
        $(this).find (".background_normal").collapse ('hide');
        $(this).find (".background_hover").collapse ('show');
    });
    $("#nav_bar a").mouseout (function () {
        $(this).find (".background_hover").collapse ('hide');
        $(this).find (".background_normal").collapse ('show');
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** I've found a workaround to the issue, but I don't really consider it an answer, as it doesn't prevent or fix this in any way. I ended up adding another element below the rest that changed color on mouseover/mouseout to mimic the element that didn't collapse correctly. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/exr4hv8z/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#nav_bar a").hover (function () {
        $(this).find (".background_normal").collapse ('hide');
        $(this).find (".background_hover").collapse ('show');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find (".background_hover").collapse ('hide');
        $(this).find (".background_normal").collapse ('show');
    });
});
```